# Vb.Net Get Resposnes form called API using WebClient

Tags: json, .net, vb.net, http, webapi

Currently, I am developing a web service which going to be called post JSON. It works fine and I got my records posted without any issue.

My issue is to display the response. I used UploadData to send .. Do I need to use download data to receive? What if I need to show in the response in MessageBox.

Note that I am expecting a response in JSON format as well. Let me know at least the concept ?  First I guess, I need to receive the response and I will deserialize it.

Here is my current code. Working fine but I can't show the response.

```
Public Function postData(ByVal JsonBody As String) As Boolean
       
     Dim webClient As New WebClient()
        Dim resByte As Byte()
        Dim resString As String
        Dim reqString() As Byte

        Try

            Dim APIusername As String = "XXXXX"
            Dim APIPassword As String = "XXXXX"
            webClient.Headers("content-type") = "application/json"
            webClient.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(APIusername, APIPassword)
            reqString = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(JsonBody)
            resByte = webClient.UploadData(Me.urlToPost, "post", reqString)
            resString = Encoding.Default.GetString(resByte)
            Console.WriteLine(resString)

            
' Here I need to show the responses

 
            webClient.Dispose()
 
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            
        End Try
        Return False
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used http request instead of web client and it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).